# Extract string from columns and paste it in the column values in R

Tags: r, names

This is an example of my initial table:

| A35.Factor1 | A36.Factor2 |
| --- | --- |
| level1 | level3 |
| level2 | level4 |

My desired output is:

| Factor1 | Factor2 |
| --- | --- |
| A35.level1 | A36.level3 |
| A35.level2 | A36. level4 |

My guess was to iterate through each column, extract the string through a regular expression and paste it using mutate() to the existing column, something like:

```
for(i in 1:ncol(dataset)) {     
  code <- colnames(dataset[,i])
  code <- str_extract(code, "A[:digit:]")
  dataset[ , i] <- dataset[, i] %>% mutate(dataset[,I] = paste(dataset[,i], code))
}
```

But it is not working, I guess I am reasoning in a bad way...
thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide a minimal sample of your data with `dput()`? It makes helping you way easier. The first thing I see is that you need to add a `+` behind `[:digit:]` to match one or more digits. otherwise it only matches one digit.

Comment: You can use `tidyr::pivot_longer(D, everything(), names_to = "factor_name", values_to = "val")`, to make a long-format table, then `tidyr::separate(..., into = c("A", "level"), sep = "\\.")` to split your values, then `dplyr::mutate` to glue the desired values together, and finally `tidyr::pivot_wider` to make your target table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
df[] <- mapply(paste0, gsub("\\..*", ".", names(df)), df)
names(df) <- gsub(".*\\.", "", names(df))
```

```r
     Factor1    Factor2
1 A35.level1 A36.level3
2 A35.level2 A36.level4
```

---

data

```r
df <- read.table(header = T, text = "A35.Factor1    A36.Factor2
level1  level3
level2  level4")
```